# Accessing an array in PHP with no name

Tags: php, json

I am trying to access decoded json elements that is in just one array, example:

```
 [
    {
    timestamp: 1509523044,
    tid: 83450451,
    price: "6381.0",
    amount: "1.0",
    type: "sell"
    },
    {
    timestamp: 1509523044,
    tid: 83450448,
    price: "6380.0",
    amount: "1.12894377",
    type: "buy"
    }
 ]
```

I have tried

```
$json = json_decode($result); 

echo $json[0]->price;
echo $json->[0]price;
echo $json->[0]->price;
```

Keep getting errors such as:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

How can i acess each indivudal element with no array name? Thanks

Comment: Do you use valid JSON? Property names should be with double quotes

Comment: Hi Jigar, I am pulling it from rest api

Comment: var_dump($json) and what is the output?

Comment: This is not a valid json

Comment: In my case I was able to access what I needed with empty string as the key.  `$neededData = $myArray['']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `json_decode` you get an object. If you need an array you have to set the second parameter to `true`.

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
```

Otherwise you have an object and you have to access all like an object. You can check that with `var_dump($json);`. Generally it's better to work with the object version instead of the array version. But sometimes you need arrays.

Edit:

what i've written in the comment your json is not valid but with the original one you gave me it's working well.

```
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD'), true));
```

with your example input it's working.

Comment: If I try that I get Notice: Undefined offset: 0
echo $json[0]['price']; or am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: I've tested you json i think that is not valid and you get "NULL" on your `var_dump`.

Comment: Hi Stony, I am getting it from
https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD

Comment: This is not the json you have on the description. The names are inside double-quotes.

Comment: Can you stop teaching people using `json_decode` with `false` as second parameter? Its `true` as default for a good reason, as stdObject are all fine to use in code and it this represents the json better than faltten it to arrays. Also Rands first approach `$json[0]->price;`, would work perfectly fine, if the array would be valid.

Comment: @FabianN. no ;) that is my answer ;) and i don't teach people how to use it. I've written that you get an object if you read my answer ;) so i've written "If you need an array" ... so please don't tell me how to write my answers thx ;)

Comment: Oh, my comment is flipped, excahnge `false` with `true` and `true` with `false`

Answer (score 4):

Your json is malformed: in order to have a valid json you should have something like this:

```
<?php
$a = '[{
    "timestamp": 1509523044,
    "tid": 83450451,
    "price": "6381.0",
    "amount": "1.0",
    "type": "sell"
},
{
    "timestamp": 1509523044,
    "tid": 83450448,
    "price": "6380.0",
    "amount": "1.12894377",
    "type": "buy"
}
]';
$b = json_decode($a, true);
var_dump($b);
```

This will return the array you need

Comment: It has to be mentioned, that the first approach from Rand (`$json[0]->price`), would only work with `json_decode($a, false);`. And for a good reason, as stdObject are all fine to use in code, this represents the json better than faltten it to arrays.

Comment: Well, it depends on his needs. In the above code he's trying to decode a malformed json and then use it as an array. I have provided the answer to that specific scenario.

Comment: Regardless, that its malformed, the outer thing is an array, thus accessing with `[0]`, but the inner one is a object, thus acessing with `->price`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not a correct json you have to make it correct before decoding.

Here I use regex to replace the keys to "keys".

```
$str = ' [
{
timestamp: 1509523044,
tid: 83450451,
price: "6381.0",
amount: "1.0",
type: "sell"
},
{
timestamp: 1509523044,
tid: 83450448,
price: "6380.0",
amount: "1.12894377",
type: "buy"
}
]';


$json = json_decode(preg_replace('/(\w+):/', '"$1":', $str));
Echo $json[0]->price;
```

https://3v4l.org/MMTvm